# show mysql rollup data in html row without separate column in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to show mysql rollup count figure in the next row once one group by is finished.

Currently, following piece of code works up to some expectation.

```html
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(em.emp_name) as count_room, COALESCE (em.emp_code, 'tot') as emp_code, em.* FROM employee_master em where em.room_id = '$room_id' GROUP BY em.emp_name WITH ROLLUP ";

$retval1 = mysql_query($query1);
$num_row1 = mysql_num_rows($retval1);
                                                
if($num_row1 >=1) {
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       $emp_code = $row1['emp_code'];
       $emp_name = $row1['emp_name'];
  echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .  $emp_code . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $emp_name . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row1['count_room'] . "</td>";      // do not want to create this column but show in a row colspan 5 once one group by ends.  
        echo "<td>" . $block_name1 . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $floor_name1 . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $room_no1 . "</td>";                         
  echo "</tr>";
  }
}
```

Where do I place `$row1['count_room']` so that the extra column is not created and show the total COUNT in the next row once one group by ends. There are going to be multiple groups.

Right now, the data looks like below.

```html
emp_code  emp_name  room_count  block_name1  floor_name1    room_no1
1         name1       1           A             G             1 
2         name2       1           A             G             1
3         name3       1           A             G             1
TOT                   3           A             G             1
11         name11     1           A             G             2 
22         name22     1           A             G             2
33         name33     1           A             G             2
44         name44     1           A             G             2
TOT                   4           A             G             2
```

However, the desired output in html using php is suppose to look like below.

```html
emp_code  emp_name    block_name1  floor_name1    room_no1
    1      name1          A             G             1 
    2      name2          A             G             1
    3      name3          A             G             1
    TOT       3           A             G             1
    11      name11        A             G             2 
    22      name22        A             G             2
    33      name32        A             G             2
    44      name44        A             G             2
    TOT       4           A             G             2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the fact that `$emp_code == 'TOT'` to change what was output in the `emp_name` column i.e. change

```
    echo "<td>" . $emp_name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['count_room'] . "</td>";
```

to

```
    echo "<td>" . ($emp_code == 'TOT' ? $row1['count_room'] : $emp_name) . "</td>";
```

You would also need to remove the code which creates the header for the `room_count` column as well.